# Ending a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have an html page that links to a js file that has the following function:

```
function show360Simple( divContainerId, imageUrl )
```

The function gets called on an on-click:

```
<area onclick="show360Simple('pContainer5','images/porch1.jpg');">
```

And I want to know how to end the function with another on-click:

```
<div id="close-div" onclick="what is the syntax here to end the above function?"></div>
```

Its probably simple but I'm a novice and haven't been able to work it out yet - any help is greatly appreciated - cheers.

Comment: I'm guessing that function does something related to 360 something, like an animation etc. and without seeing the function it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Are you using [this script](http://www.mind2b.com/component/content/article/9-info/2-360-panoramic-javascript-virtual-tour-free)?

Comment: More importantly, are you able to edit the js file?

Comment: @dc5, yes that is the script I am using.

Comment: @user1822445 As HodofHod alluded to, basically the only way you're going to stop the function (I'm assuming you're referring to the series to `setTimeout` actions), is to edit the source code and insert some kind of condition that checks some value set by the second onClick event you mentioned.

Comment: @Teeg thank you - hmmm, yes I think I need to create another function in the source js that ends all the previous ones and then run it on the on-click - do I sound like I'm on the right track here?

Comment: @user1822445 I'm 100% sure what you mean; if by "another function" you mean some sort of onClick handler that would set the "animation loop" control variable I mentioned, then yes I believe so. But take a look at dc5's answer, that's way better.

Answer (score 2):

The script linked above is using `setTimeout` to manage the animation.

To stop, you will need to modify the code a bit and add a stop function.

The simplest approach would be to store off the timeoutId returned from each `setTimeout` call.  Then, in the stop function, call `clearTimeout` passing in the stored timeoutId.

Without making too many changes:

```
// Declare a global timeoutId
var timeoutId;
```

In `function show360` change the setTimeout call to:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(…);
```

In `function move360` change the setTimeout call to:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(…);
```

Then add a stop360 function:

```
function stop360() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}
```

<kbd>[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/JLGyb/1/)</kbd>

This will stop the animation - basically freezing it.  If you want to remove the changes made by the script you could change the stop function to something like this:

```
function stop360(divContainerId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    if(divContainerId) {
        var o = document.getElementById(divContainerId);
        o.style.backgroundImage = '';
        o.style.position = "";
        o.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo with Clear](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/JLGyb/2/)</kbd>

Comment: @user1822445 Don't forget to accept dc5's answer if it helped you (click the checkmark to the left of the question)